# Replace synchronous Prototype.js AJAX with jQuery AJAX and Promises

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, prototypejs

I have a prototype.js synchronous ajax call that I need to convert to a jQuery ajax call using Promises.

Here is basically what I'm starting with.

```
// synchronous prototype.js ajax function
function isSwitchOn() {

    var isOn = false;

    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request('checkSwitch', {
        method: 'post', asynchronous: false, evalJSON: 'force', requestHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },

        onSuccess: function (transport) {
            if (isValidResponse(transport)) {
                if (transport.responseJSON.result == "switched") {
                    isOn = true;
                }
            }
        },
        onFailure: function (oXHR, oJson) { handleFailure(oXHR.status); },
        onException: function (request, err) { handleException(request, err); }
    });

    return isOn;
}

//calling function snippet
do {
    // complex stuff that affects switch status and manages UI
} while (!isSwitchOn());
```

This is my conversion attempt but it's not setting switchStateOn prior to the loop assessment.

```
function handleSwitchResponse(response) {
    if (isValidResponse(response)) {
        if (response.result == "switched") {
            return true;
        }
    }    
    return false;
}

function checkSwitch() {
    return getJson('checkSwitch')
               .then( function (data) { return data; })
               .fail( function (oXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { handleException(oXHR, textStatus + ": " + errorThrown.message); });
}

function getJson(url) {
    return jQuery.ajax(url, { method: 'POST', dataType: 'json' });
}

//calling function snippet
var switchStateOn;
do {
    // complex stuff that affects switch status and manages UI

    checkSwitch().then(function (response) { switchStateOn = handleSwitchResponse(response); });
} while (!switchStateOn);
```

Can anyone help architect this appropriately using jQuery AJAX and Promises?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to make the loop async too.

Comment: Currently, the iterations of the loop themselves have an intrinsic order.  I'm not sure what you mean by "make the loop async too".  Can you elaborate?